# I need help about deploying a windows application

Tags: vb.net

I have visited http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/libr...(v=VS.71).aspx. I have learned many things. But it didnt make clear about those files what I have used there in my program. I know I can add additional files. Does it mean that I have to add those files there in additional file dialog box what I have used there in my program like images. Even I have created pic forlder there in debug folder to save pic how should I add it there in my setup file? I am totally confused. I have searched there in gogole but it doesnt say anything about source files like images & anyother thinkgs like text to speack .dll grid .dll. I thought it will combine them together automatically. Please tell me step by step how should I do it. Once I thought I have to add all files present there in debug folder. I am totally confused please help me.

Comment: The link doesn't work, this is a non-programming related question and please use formatting/paragraphs.

Comment: Did you try google instead of gogole?? . Can you explain clearly what exactly is you problem/

Answer (score 1):

Have you added a setup project to your solution?  You start there.  Then you can add images or whatever else you need to the setup project.

Anything referenced in your project (like grid .dll files or any other .dlls you're using) should get included automatically.